# CSS Check if Image OR Button is hovered if not hovered then apply style

Tags: css, css-animations, mousehover

> I have an image with a button inside when i hover the image both the image and button becomes larger and when i move my mouse outside the image they go back to normal. the issue is when i move my cursor over the Button inside the image the image goes back to normal size, i want the image to  only go back to normal size if neither the image or button is being hovered.

```
 .ProjectImage:hover ~ .ProjectLiveVersionButton {
 -webkit-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

// is there a way to check if image or button is hovered?
 // something like this

.ProjectImage:not(:hover)  &&(AND) .ProjectLiveVersionButton:not(:hover)  {
 -webkit-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
   transition-timing-function: ease;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
```

Comment: I suspect you don't mean the button is inside the img (imgs don't have content) but is following it. Could you show the relevant HTML, preferably make your code into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could put them both in a container and sense hover on that perhaps

Comment: Thanks !  both the image and button was inside a div so i just added the hover to the div instead and it worked.